# MongoDB Log Levels

Tags: mongodb

In mongodb you can set the log level to between 0 and 5. I was wondering what the general behavior of each of these levels was and what level it should be set at to keep from logging inserts. Its annoying to go through a log when you get around 600ips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I think I solved it. Even though mongodb was reporting a log level of 0 it apparently wasnt. When I started playing with the log levels I tried various number to look for changes in the log. But when I set it back to 0 it stopped logging the inserts.

Comment: did you check to see what you are setting your logging to in the event of a restart?  Maybe you did set it in the past but a restart reset things.....check out your config file and/or command line options.

Answer (score 5):

Actually this is probably a function of the --slowms setting rather than the logging level - the default is 100ms.  Increase that and the number of logged inserts should decrease.  It's discussed, with examples, here:

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Database+Profiler#DatabaseProfiler-EnablingProfiling

Comment: According to db.getProfilingLevel() my profiling level is 0 and thus should be turned off and a quick db.system.profile.find() confirms it.